# org-babel for haskell not works of eval haskell block

Tags: haskell, emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I am use org-mode blogging, I use org-babel to evaluate the code as following :

```
#+BEGIN_SRC haskell
import Data.Function (fix)

f :: Int -> Int
f = (+ 1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
      putStrLn $ show $ f 1
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: <interactive>:9:25: Not in scope: ‘f’
```

I found the org-babel for haskell use infer-haskell mode to start session and eval the code. I also say the session was created, and if I don't define the function but directly putStrLn "hello" , it works.

hope anyone can fix the bug :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC haskell
import Data.Function (fix)

f :: Int -> Int
let f = (+ 1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
      putStrLn $ show $ f 1
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 2
```

Org's babel mode is running the Haskell code with ghci. In ghci you are required to use let to declare functions.

Comment: I do wonder how tangle handles extracting this to a source file since `let f` would be invalid in a Haskell source file. For those not familiar with tangle: http://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-source-code.html

Comment: I'm a couple years late but to clear it up for everyone who stumbles upon this: it simply doesnt, tangle doesn't work properly when combined with variables in haskell

Answer (score 6):

In this [article](http://quickhack.net/nom/blog/2012-08-31-org-babel-and-haskell.html), Yoshinari Nomura describes a way to evaluate Haskell blocks using `runhaskell` via a Ruby script. I do not understand japanese, so I cannot translate the details, but the method has allowed me to run haskell blocks without having to write specifically for the interpreter.

Comment: This saved my day after trying around for 2 hours ... thanks.